# Windows Services - How can I find the darktable instance in windows services

Tags: powershell, schedule, darktable

I accidentally screwed up my darktable configuration, so I reloaded it from scratch. To avoid losing all my recorded changes I have done to my pictures, I wrote a powershell backup script for the darktable database. I want to launch this script from the windows task scheduler when ever I launch darktable. I have found the event id which indicates in the security log of a new process has occurred which I should be able to use to automatically launch my backup script from task scheduler. I want to add code to the script to check the services to see if darktable is actually running and only perform the backup if it is. Anyone know how I can identify this?

Comment: I assume you want to run your backup BEFORE you run DarkTable? In that case I'd just write a PS Script to run the backup then run DarkTable and then run the PS Script from a shortcut or a shortcut pointing to TaskScheduler if you want to launch DT as an admin and don't want to hassle with the elevation prompts.

Comment: Ok, that answer just made me slap my head(remember Bull from Night Court) in recognition of me having an ah du moment. You're absolutely right. Just modify the backup script I wrote to launch darktable after the backup is complete.  And while I am at it, I might as well add an idiot check to insure my external drive with my pictures are mounted before doing anything.  Thank you @RetiredGeek